# I have a situation with OSPF and EIGRP which requires a specific trace route. How can I get this to work?

Tags: networking, routing

Objective: Traffic should follow from R1->R3->R4->R6->R7->R8->R9->R10

In traceroute/extended ping :
178.41.41.13,) (
178.41.41.34,
178.41.41.76,
178.41.41.137,
178.41.41.228,
178.41.41.234,
178.41.41.242.

What I did is filter R8,9,10 with route-map and distribute-lists, so that traffic goes from R6 to R7 but it doesn't. It just goes from R6 to 178.41.41.138 and 178.41.41.139. Can anyone help this out?

Image:

[image: Image:]

Comment: Is this really a business scenario? It looks more like a course homework.

Comment: The world doesn't need people with degrees who don't know anything. If you want a certificate, work hard to have one. Do your homework yourself. This is the only way to learn something.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is contrary to the nature of routing protocols like OSPF or EIGRP.
Routing protocols are not intended for creating specific fixed routes but for determining routes dynamically from the current network situation. If you need a specific route you already know, configure it as a static route.

Comment: Thanks but I'm sure we can alter the routing paths between them. I just can't work it out in that order.

Comment: Sure, you could go and tweak the metrics until you get the results you want, but you'd be putting the cart before the horse. I cannot imagine a business scenario where that approach would make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the routing metric (cost) to make your desired route preferred.

Comment: I tried changing AD, cost but the packet from 178.41.41.76 is moving to 178.41.41.138 and then to 178.41.41.242. Here we want it to move from 178.41.41.137-178.41.41.227-178.41.41.234 and then to 178.41.41.242. Can you help with it ?

Comment: AD is not the metric.  It only determines which routing protocol is preferred.  You want to change the OSPF cost.  Make it lower on preferred links.

Comment: Thank you for that. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: Hello there, I tried changing metrics on the routers but still, I could only get it to work up to 178.41.41.227 in the order i.e, 178.41.41.76 - 178.41.41.137 - 178.41.41.227. After that, it just comes through 178.41.41.138 to 178.41.41.233 again. Any idea of what to do?